# How to fill Bootstrap 3 column with a color while remaining outer padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: I need to fill the areas marked with red with white color]

I'm working on a site which will use Bootstrap 3. The site will mainly use dark background-color but for a header-row containing a logo and a menu the background-color should be white. However! I do not want the white color to fill the entire width (all the way to the "container" boundries). The attached image illustrates what I would like to do. The row contains 2 columns, one is 2 cols wide and the other one is 10 cols wide. I would like to fill the entire row with white but I do NOT want it to span the "padding" or margins marked with green (those shall remain blue). What's the best suggestion for doing this?

OK, maybe I'm bad on explaining but I'll give it another shot ;)

I've expanded the example given to better show what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/RedRockerSE/47Fsr/

I can't see how: `background-clip: content-box;` do this?

I want the outer "padding/margin/gutter"-areas (marked with arrows below) to be filled with the background-color (or NOT to be filled with the rows background-color if you will). The "padding/margin/gutter"-areas between the cols SHOULD be filled with the row background-color.
[image]

Comment: can you try *{margin:0;padding:0} in your css stylesheet

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear what you are trying to achieve here. In your JSFiddle you would get rid of the white by not assinging white as the background colour to `.row`, but I think you are trying to achieve something different..?

Comment: I DO want the row background-color to be white but I do NOT want it to expand all the way to the outer padding-areas marked with arrows. I've tried wrapping the columns but with no luck.

Comment: You can add a `15px` margin to the `.row` (if you need it) and then override the bootstrap padding on the first and last `.col-xs-4` elements _(not fully supported by legacy browsers)_: http://jsfiddle.net/47Fsr/2/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 bg-color"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 bg-color"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 bg-color"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css code

```
body {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.row {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.col-xs-4 {
  background-clip: content-box;
  height: 100px;
}
.bg-color {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to user .row .no-gutter

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row no-gutter">
     <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #f00;
}
.col-xs-4 {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47Fsr/7/

Comment: `.no-gutter` isn't actually a thing in bootstrap that I know of. On your demo, removing the class has no effect. Putting color on the col-* alone achieves what you've done.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this;

```
[class^=col-].no-space-left {
 padding-left:0;
}

[class^=col-].no-space-right {
  padding-right:0;
}
```

and add inner div padding;

```
[class^=col-].no-space-left > div {
  padding:0 15px
  /*padding-right:15px;*/ /*if you want no space between col- */
}

[class^=col-].no-space-right > div {
    padding:0 15px
  /*padding-left:15px;*/ /*if you want no space between col- */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47Fsr/32/